# Get data from a vue component child and bind to an object in parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

`<user-data @change="setUserInfo"></user-data">`
this is the child component where have used `emits` to pass data.

here is the method of parent component.

```js
 setUserInfo(data) {
   this.obj.payment_details = data;
 },
```

is it possible to bind data from the above method?

```js
export default {
    data: () => ({
        dialog: false,
        obj: new Expense(),
        saveLoader: false,
    }),
}
```

Comment: What do you want to say with `is it possible to bind data from the above method?`.
What result you want?

Comment: Usually, you use emits+props. Then, the parent/child relationship is a matter of reactive by default if properly done. No extra work needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an example on how to emit data from child component to parent (using Vue3 Composition API script setup):

Parent:

```html
<template>
  <Comp @my-var="callback" />
  
  {{ test }}
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'
const test = ref('')

const callback = data => test.value = data
</script>
```

Child:

```html
<template>
<button
  v-text="'click'"
  @click="doEmit()"
/>
</template>

<script setup>
const emits = defineEmits(['myVar'])

const doEmit = () => emits('myVar', 'emiting this data')
</script>
```

Check out [the Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqFUcFugzAM/RUrl1BpwL2iVadpv7DL2CGloU1LSJQYtgrx77NDW1W77ICEn/38nl8m8ep9MQ5arEWF2vpOod7WPUD15qyHnb3mowqbWjSq6/aqudQCyjTA3zQB6ogwz3VflU98KmMTjEeIGgdPiLHeBYQJgm5hhjY4C5KE5aOVBBe8KLlgX9RuXE8SSWfD7EzKFSss+N0X9Q4KFWy2abQYVTfoG8jmFjtkRLyIRTC3yhfn6Hq6fUoX3RqxFmtICGNkgutanBB9XJdlbBt2do6FC8eS/oow9GisLnS0+T6476gDLa4Fr6BkZpK83/Mn52o/IDo6BmDMUf8gJS2bzjQXudB3qSD04N6twWzFMD/AP3Ev4WiiRA5Bt6bXvCBmn9JeP1SQX08hLstpMFtxgImW3eZeQHJt+iPgycQUKD/AI1Ix/wLRNcfT)

Comment: am on vue2 is it possible too